# Extract parameters in an string an replace them with their values which are in another map with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a map like this:

`var params = { 'name':'Mehran', 'city':'Isfahan'};`

and I also have a string like this:

`var welcomeText = 'Hi {{name}}! {{city}} is a beautiful city.';`

My purpose is to replace the `{{name}}` and `{{city}}` with their values in `params` with a `render()` function.

`var result = render(welcomeText, params);`

And the `result` would be something like this:

`'Hi Mehran! Isfahan is a beautiful city.'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at nice [Mustache project](http://mustache.github.com/) which does exactly what you are after with other useful options for you to use.

[Working Example](http://mustache.github.com/#demo)

---

Here is quick and dirty custom way though:

```
function render(text, data){
    for (var i in data){
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            text = text.replace('{{' + i + '}}', data[i]);            
        }
    }

    return text;
}

var params = { 'name':'Mehran', 'city':'Isfahan'};
var welcomeText = 'Hi {{name}}! {{city}} is a beautiful city.';

var txt = render(welcomeText, params);
console.log(txt); // Hi Mehran! Isfahan is a beautiful city.
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a really nice project.